# Do the following operations on the elliptic curve $ \ y^2 = x^3 + x + 26 $ over $ \mathbb{Z}_{127} \ $

Tags: number-theory

Do the following operations on the elliptic curve  $ \ y^2 = x^3 + x + 26$ over  $ \mathbb{Z}_{127}  $.

**(a)**  $ (9,16)+(6,11) \ $

**(b)**  $ -(11,15) \ $

**Answer:**

We know that ,

If $ P_1=(x_1,y_1) \ \ and \ \ P_2=(x_2,y2) \ $ of the ellipse $ y^2=x^3+ax+b \ $ , then

$ P_3 =(x_3,y_3) =P_1+P_2 $ is given by

$ x_3=\lambda^2-x_2-x_1 \ \ and \ \ y_3=\lambda (x_1-x_3)-y_1 \ $

where

$ \lambda = \begin{align} \frac{x_2-x_1}{y_2-y_1}, \ if \ P_1 \neq P_2 \\ \frac{3x_1^2+a}{2y_1}, \ if \ P_1=P_2 \end{align} $

**But when I calculate it becomes complicated. 
Any help is there ?**

Comment: Yes, computing addition on elliptic curves by hand is tiresome. The best thing to do is to train your computer to do it for you.

Comment: can you tell me $ \ -(11,15)= ? $ in the above ellipse ?

Comment: Negatives are easy on a curve $y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$: $[-1](x_0,y_0)=(x_0,-y_0)$.